# Is there way to outline static variable for a method?

Tags: java, android

How can i shorten code for particular method if there are a lot of variables like

```
Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.THREAD_ID,
Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.BODY,
Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.TYPE
```

As you see it take just a lot of space. I know that it is possible to make static import for class like

```
import static android.provider.Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.*;
```

However it will clash with other static import (i have multiple variable TYPE and other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define constants in the class with different names:

```
class YourClass {
  static final int YOUR_DIFFERENT_NAME = Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.THREAD_ID;

  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code you provide it seems those variables can be defined as enums, so you can import enum and use its enumerated values. As example

```
public enum TextBasedSmsColumns {
    THREAD_ID,
    THREAD_ID2,
    THREAD_ID3,
    //...
    THREAD_IDN;
}
```